# Pandas.read_csv() ignore bad lines/rows containing FEWER fields. Text file

Tags: python, pandas, text, read.csv

I am trying to read this huge text file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ikikw8bxde6y1i/TCAD_SPECIAL%20EXPORT_2019_20200409.zip?dl=0 (if you download the zip, the file is Special_ARB.txt (not necessary for my question imo).

I am running this code (adding `error_bad_lines=False`) to ignore lines with more-than-expected fields, which works well:

```
pd.read_csv(r'~/Special_ARB.txt', sep="|", 
            header=None,encoding='cp1252',error_bad_lines=False)
```

The problem is that `read.csv()` crashed when a line had only 1 field. With the following error:

> Too many columns specified: expected 77 and found 1

Is there a way to tell python/pandas to ignore this error? It is not letting me know which line it is. There are more than a million rows so I can't just find it on my own.

- I tried a for loop to read line by line and figure it out from there, but data is so large that python crashed.
- The number of columns is 77 which is correctly identify by pandas when running the code, I don't think that's an issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

- [Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)
- [Python Try Except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

```
try:
   pd.read_csv(r'~/Special_ARB.txt', sep="|", header=None,encoding='cp1252',error_bad_lines=False)
except <your error description>:
   <do this>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Exception handling needs to be done line by line, not across the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for in-memory datasets, you can use chunking for a solution on large datasets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331754/9379924